# Angularjs, how to reset directive variables when button clicked in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

First of all, I'm sorry to ask simple like below.

I have no code to show you.

Maybe this seems like a kind of rude question, but I expect somebody will give me some examples.

I've succeeded to link `directive` and `controller`.

I built modal like this link.

[Add element dynamically by using Modal](https://jsfiddle.net/CRDeity/6kmszgL0/1/)

In my original code, modal have a button to close itself.

What I want is when I click this button, all variables related with directive to be initialized.

But I don't know how.

Help me please. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why don't you use a service?? Just broadcast and catch the event in directive and reset your variable.

Comment: @anu Well, okay. I'll consider your suggestion. But I want ways more simple or easy. thanks to your comments. :)

Comment: Is this `ng2?` or `the old one?`. Use `$scope.$broadcast('eventsomethingreset')` then catch it on your directive `$scope.$on('eventsomethingreset', func () { //reset stuff })'` if `ng1` else if `ng2` use [RxJS Observable](https://blog.lacolaco.net/post/event-broadcasting-in-angular-2/)

Comment: @masterpreenz the old one what I'm using. I'll try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**ng-if** will re-render the element to which it is applied

For Example

In html

```
<my-directive ng-if="reRender"></my-directive>

<button ng-click="resetDirective();">Reset Directive</button>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.reRender = true; //initial value

$scope.resetDirective = function(){
    $scope.reRender = false;
    var timer = $timeout(function(){
        $scope.reRender = true;
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
    }, 500);
}
```